# segment customers based on RFM score and create pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

i have done RFM analysis on a purchase history data.[image]

based on the RFM class i have segmented the customers, since some of my customer belonging to more than one category i have to segment customer to their belonging class and add to my rfm table (adding a separate column 'segment')

CardNo    Recency    Frequency   Monetary   R_Quartile  F_Quartile  M_Quartile  RFMClass   Segment

my rfmtable columns looks like the above excluding the column 'segment' --which i want to add to the rfm table

what i have done so far is

```
for card_no in rfmSegmentation['CardNo']:
>     for num in rfmSegmentation['RFMClass']:
>         num = str(num)
>         if int(num[0])==1 and int(num[1])==1 and int(num[2])==1:
>             print("RFM_class",num,"cardno",card_no,"Best Customer")
>         elif int(num[1])==1:
>             print("RFM_class",num,"cardno",card_no,"Loyal Customer")
>         elif int(num[2])==1:
>             print("RFM_class",num,"cardno",card_no,"Big Spender")
>         elif int(num[0])==3 and int(num[1])==1 and int(num[2])==1:  
>             print("RFM_class",num,"cardno",card_no,"Almost Lost")        
>         elif int(num[0])==4 and int(num[1])==1 and int(num[2])==1:   
>             print("RFM_class",num,"cardno",card_no,"Lost Customer")
>         elif int(num[0])==4 and int(num[1])==4 and int(num[2])==4:  
>             print("RFM_class",num,"cardno",card_no,"Lost Cheap Customer")
```

it prints the segment of each customer but i want to add this as a separate column in rfmtable and convert it to a csv file

any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is actually a `pandas ` & `dataframe` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` (tag removed); consider also changing the title to be descriptive of the actual question...

Comment: done............

Comment: Could you post an example of your data with desired output? Please don't use pictures.

Comment: You can use apply function for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 > I think I found a solution
    > 
    > segment = []
    > 
    >  for row in rfmSegmentation['RFMClass']:
    >     row = str(row)
    >     if int(row[0])==1 and int(row[1])==1 and int(row[2])==1:
    >         segment.append('Best Customer')
    >     elif int(row[1])==1:
    >         segment.append('Loyal Customer')
    >     elif int(row[2])==1:
    >         segment.append('Big Spender')
    >     elif int(row[0])==3 and int(row[1])==1 and int(row[2])==1:
    >         segment.append('Almost Lost')
    >     elif int(row[0])==4 and int(row[1])==1 and int(row[2])==1: 
    >         segment.append('Lost Customer')
    >     elif int(row[0])==4 and int(row[1])==4 and int(row[2])==4:
    >         segment.append('Lost Cheap Customer')
    >     else:
    >         segment.append('Failed')
    >         
    >  rfmSegmentation['segment'] = segment
```